# Objective-C invalidate timer in another method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, timer, nstimer, invalidation

I have a method in which i have declared a timer;

```
- (void)startTimer:(id)sender {
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.8
                                                     target: self
                                                   selector: @selector(toggleButtonImage:)
                                                   userInfo: nil
                                                    repeats: YES];  
}
```

What i want to do is, in another method i want to invalidate the timer if it is running, here's the what i have so far but i get the error 'timer is undeclared'

```
- (void)stopTimer:(id)sender {
    if ( [timer isValid]) {
      [timer invalidate], timer=nil;
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both methods are on the same controller, then simply make the timer an instance variable. If they are not on the same object, you should rethink your design as two classes are trying to manage the same facility.

Comment: They are both in the same controller, how would i make the timer an instance variable, please could you explain, i'm new to objective-c.

Comment: @Sami: glad you solved your problem, and glad my answer helped. On developer.apple.com there's a guide to Objective-C which may give you more insight. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html